# Issue with line 450 of an XSD file doesn't let me convert it to XML

Tags: xml, xsd, liquid-xml

I've been trying to convert an XSD file to XML. It is a formulary provided by a government agency in order to be able to report some required data.

The XML schema says it was created by LiquidStudio, which is the reason I'm here. I've tried using the online converting tool by the same company but it marks two errors on line 450.
I'm totally lost, please help.

Here's the line that marks the errors:

450:

```html
<xs:pattern value="[A-ZÑ&]{3,4}[0-9]{2}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][A-Z0-9]?[A-Z0-9]?[0-9A-Z]"/>
```

The message for the two errors are as follow:
"The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference." and "The reference to entity "null" must end with the ';' delimiter."

Here's the link to the XSD file I need to convert: http://formulario.cre.gob.mx/Content/templates/514/v1/volumenesExpendio.xsd

Comment: This is an exact copy of [this question 35 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64434321/problems-converting-an-xsd-to-a-xml).

Comment: @zx485 yes it is since the other one got blocked for some reason. Can you please help a noob??

Comment: Yes it was - and it was for a good reason. Please take a tour through [the Help Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). For example, linking to a complete offsite resource (like your XSD in this case) is not helpful for other visitors of this site, because offsite resources can disappear - rendering the question useless. So learn about the benefits of a [mcve] and other behaviour that is relevant to using this site.

Comment: @zx485 very well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The line in question should be as follows:

```
<xs:pattern value="[A-ZÑ&amp;]{3,4}[0-9]{2}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][A-Z0-9]?[A-Z0-9]?[0-9A-Z]"/>
```

**XML sample**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReporteVolumenes xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="volumenesExpendio.xsd"
                  FechaReporteEstadistico="30/11/2085" Version="ABCD"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <EstacionesServicioVolumen>
        <EstacionServicioVolumen numeroPermisoCRE="PL/666/EXP/ESA/2014"
                                 RFC="YWÑ050939XNX" ImagenComercialId="2854"
                                 EstatusESId="9914">
            <EstacionServicioVolumenesComprados>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenComprado ProductoId="3079"
                                                 SubProductoId="4723"
                                                 SubproductoMarcaId="2636"
                                                 TipoCompra="0"
                                                 VolumenComprado="4127"
                                                 RecibioDescuento="1"
                                                 PagoServicioFlete="0"
                                                 PermisoTransportistaCRE="PL/663/TRA/TM/2070"/>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenComprado ProductoId="4579"
                                                 SubProductoId="876"
                                                 SubproductoMarcaId="7305"
                                                 TipoCompra="1"
                                                 VolumenComprado="2201"
                                                 RecibioDescuento="0"
                                                 PagoServicioFlete="1"
                                                 PermisoTransportistaCRE="PL/80693/TRA/DUC/2063"/>
            </EstacionServicioVolumenesComprados>
            <EstacionServicioVolumenesVendidosInventarios>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenVendidoInventarios ProductoId="7041"
                                                           SubProductoId="173"
                                                           SubproductoMarcaId="490"
                                                           InventarioInicial="9084"
                                                           VolumenVendido="7767"
                                                           InventarioFinal="4104"
                                                           ExportaProducto="1"/>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenVendidoInventarios ProductoId="7439"
                                                           SubProductoId="5851"
                                                           SubproductoMarcaId="2174"
                                                           InventarioInicial="7093"
                                                           VolumenVendido="9005"
                                                           InventarioFinal="8482"
                                                           ExportaProducto="0"/>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenVendidoInventarios ProductoId="827"
                                                           SubProductoId="3085"
                                                           SubproductoMarcaId="4152"
                                                           InventarioInicial="1720"
                                                           VolumenVendido="3187"
                                                           InventarioFinal="9462"
                                                           ExportaProducto="1"/>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenVendidoInventarios ProductoId="3475"
                                                           SubProductoId="2117"
                                                           SubproductoMarcaId="2495"
                                                           InventarioInicial="2705"
                                                           VolumenVendido="1519"
                                                           InventarioFinal="4202"
                                                           ExportaProducto="1"/>
            </EstacionServicioVolumenesVendidosInventarios>
        </EstacionServicioVolumen>
        <EstacionServicioVolumen numeroPermisoCRE="PL/468/EXP/ESA/2080"
                                 RFC="QN&amp;Ñ2010196LH" ImagenComercialId="4270"
                                 EstatusESId="793">
            <EstacionServicioVolumenesComprados>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenComprado ProductoId="8986"
                                                 SubProductoId="6206"
                                                 SubproductoMarcaId="499"
                                                 TipoCompra="false"
                                                 VolumenComprado="3047"
                                                 RecibioDescuento="true"
                                                 PagoServicioFlete="1"
                                                 PermisoTransportistaCRE="PL/1210/TRA/OM/2072"/>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenComprado ProductoId="3413"
                                                 SubProductoId="6159"
                                                 SubproductoMarcaId="2534"
                                                 TipoCompra="0"
                                                 VolumenComprado="7995"
                                                 RecibioDescuento="true"
                                                 PagoServicioFlete="0"
                                                 PermisoTransportistaCRE="PL/1771254/TRA/TM/2045"/>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenComprado ProductoId="8592"
                                                 SubProductoId="4656"
                                                 SubproductoMarcaId="4122"
                                                 TipoCompra="1"
                                                 VolumenComprado="4038"
                                                 RecibioDescuento="1"
                                                 PagoServicioFlete="1"
                                                 PermisoTransportistaCRE="PL/4790/DIS/OM/2024"/>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenComprado ProductoId="2437"
                                                 SubProductoId="9476"
                                                 SubproductoMarcaId="3529"
                                                 TipoCompra="1"
                                                 VolumenComprado="5831"
                                                 RecibioDescuento="0"
                                                 PagoServicioFlete="1"
                                                 PermisoTransportistaCRE="PL/99990/TRA/TM/2012"/>
            </EstacionServicioVolumenesComprados>
            <EstacionServicioVolumenesVendidosInventarios>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenVendidoInventarios ProductoId="6074"
                                                           SubProductoId="1437"
                                                           SubproductoMarcaId="1676"
                                                           InventarioInicial="5462"
                                                           VolumenVendido="156"
                                                           InventarioFinal="5433"
                                                           ExportaProducto="false"/>
            </EstacionServicioVolumenesVendidosInventarios>
        </EstacionServicioVolumen>
        <EstacionServicioVolumen numeroPermisoCRE="PL/13282/EXP/ESA/2091"
                                 RFC="ÑJI78180251X" ImagenComercialId="8469"
                                 EstatusESId="24">
            <EstacionServicioVolumenesComprados>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenComprado ProductoId="3338"
                                                 SubProductoId="1523"
                                                 SubproductoMarcaId="8254"
                                                 TipoCompra="0"
                                                 VolumenComprado="309"
                                                 RecibioDescuento="1"
                                                 PagoServicioFlete="1"
                                                 PermisoTransportistaCRE="PL/19136/TRA/DUC/2068"/>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenComprado ProductoId="198"
                                                 SubProductoId="6649"
                                                 SubproductoMarcaId="350"
                                                 TipoCompra="false"
                                                 VolumenComprado="7443"
                                                 RecibioDescuento="false"
                                                 PagoServicioFlete="1"
                                                 PermisoTransportistaCRE="PL/661/TRA/DUC/2019"/>
            </EstacionServicioVolumenesComprados>
            <EstacionServicioVolumenesVendidosInventarios>
                <EstacionServicioVolumenVendidoInventarios ProductoId="290"
                                                           SubProductoId="5926"
                                                           SubproductoMarcaId="8277"
                                                           InventarioInicial="3685"
                                                           VolumenVendido="9058"
                                                           InventarioFinal="8364"
                                                           ExportaProducto="0"/>
            </EstacionServicioVolumenesVendidosInventarios>
        </EstacionServicioVolumen>
    </EstacionesServicioVolumen>
</ReporteVolumenes>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue when using the XSD with our [online XSD to XML converter](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-to-xml-converter)?

I assume the issue is that you are copying incorrect XSD data as described in Yitzhak Khabinsky's answer above?